# I get zsh: parse error near `\n' whenever I try to SSH into my raspberry PI

Tags: ssh, osx, raspberry-pi, raspbian, macintosh

New user to mac/raspberry pi. I try to SSH into my pi by

ssh pi@ and I always get the error:
zsh: parse error near `\n'

What could cause this or what could I start searching for to get an answer?

Comment: You should probably be looking in your shell's startup files on the remote machine. Does the error message not contain a filename and/or line number?